# Dynamic sum column

Tags: excel, dynamic, formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&CGUs&"'!"&(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",""))),INDIRECT("'"&CGUs&"'!"&"A:A"),'Actuals Consolidated'!$A9)
```

This works however it only sums the same column in the other sheet as the cell it sits in ( If the sum is in column F it will sum column F in target sheets.

Can this be changed to find the column with the same header regardless of where it is in the target sheets?

Link to sample sheet :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nLReRzhRRLVXybL302N0G6RRCWIpRQCs/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you provide sample data, sample results and sample expectation?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated to add a link to a sample sheet.

Comment: I would look at index() with match()

Comment: Okay. I do not see the actual formulas there. And there are also lots of tabs. Can you walk us through your problem?

Comment: Please don not link to files - but instead show some sample data and expected result in your question. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).